# Meteor: Dynamic image in template

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to create a template with a dynamic loading image?

**template**

```
<template name="example">
    <img src="{{src}}">
</template>
```

**helper**

```
Template.example.helpers({
    src: function() {
        return Collection.findOne({}, { sort: { timestamp: -1 }}).url;
    }
});
```

As you can see the src-url is stored in a collection document and I always choose the newest document of the collection.

But if I insert a new document in that collection nothing happens until I do a reload of the page.

Comment: It seems as if there might be an issue with the _subscriptions_ in your app. I'd be looking at the _subscribe_ declaration in your client script.

Comment: for developing I selected all documents of the collection for the subscription. That is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDb cursors are reactive not the data itself. In your helper you are basically `fetching` one document from the database using `findOne()`. `findOne()` get one document and closes the cursor. You can try `find()` with `limit` and show it in the dom using `#each` property of Blaze.

```
Collection.find({}, {limit:1 , sort: { timestamp: -1 }});

{{#each src }}
    <img src="{{src.url}}">
{{/each}}
```

Comment: if the limit is set to 1, how can you get 2 image?